# How I correct this program (Struct & pointer(?))?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Can you help me with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    typedef struct{
        char NIM[11];
        char Nama[20];
        int mid;
        int final;
        int tugas;
        int absen;
        float nilaiakhir;
    }data;
    data datamahasiswa[10];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=1;i++){
        printf("Data Mahasiswa ke-%d\n",i);

        printf ("NIM :");
            scanf ("%s",&datamahasiswa[i].NIM);

        printf ("Nama :");
            scanf ("%s",&datamahasiswa[i].Nama);

        printf("Nilai Mid =");
            scanf("%d",&datamahasiswa[i].mid);

        printf("Nilai Final =");
            scanf("%d",&datamahasiswa[i].final);

        printf("Nilai Tugas =");
            scanf("%d",&datamahasiswa[i].tugas);

        printf("Jumlah absen =");
            scanf("%d",&datamahasiswa[i].absen);

        datamahasiswa[i].nilaiakhir=((10/100)*datamahasiswa[i].absen)+((25/100)*datamahasiswa[i].mid)+((35/100)*datamahasiswa[i].final)+((30/100)*datamahasiswa[i].tugas);
    }
    for (i=0;i<=1;i++){
        printf("Data Mahasiswa ke-%d\n",i);
        printf ("NIM : %s\n",datamahasiswa[i].NIM);
        printf ("Nama : %s\n",datamahasiswa[i].Nama);
        printf("Nilai Mid = %d\n",datamahasiswa[i].mid);
        printf("Nilai Final = %d\n",datamahasiswa[i].final);
        printf("Nilai Tugas = %d\n",datamahasiswa[i].tugas);
        printf("Jumlah absen = %d\n",datamahasiswa[i].absen);
        printf("Nilai Akhir = %f\n",datamahasiswa[i].nilaiakhir);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried this program and at the end it still return 0 on datamahasiswa[i].nilaiakhir, somehow I think I must use pointer, but I really don't know how to use pointer with struct to made this program right, anyone can help?

Comment: It is zero because you are trying to do floating point arithmetic with integers.

Comment: these divisions: (10/100), etc are using integer math.  With integer math, any remainder is lost, so (10/100) = 0.  Suggest you change (10/100) to 10.0/100.0, etc so will use floating point math, which keeps the remainder as a fractional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major problems:

- `scanf ("%s",&datamahasiswa[i].NIM);` and `scanf ("%s",&datamahasiswa[i].Nama);`: The `NIM` and `Nama` members are arrays, which means they are already pointers to their storage locations, so you need to remove the address operator `&` when passing them to `scanf()` (i.e., `scanf ("%s",datamahasiswa[i].NIM);` and `scanf ("%s",datamahasiswa[i].Nama)`).
- When you want fractional results form the division operator `/`, at least one of the operands must be of a floating type. Use something like `(double) 10 / 100`, or `10. / 100.` (note the decimal points).

Comment: BTW, you should actually at least specify a *maximum field width* when using `scanf()` to store strings with `%s`, otherwise your array buffers be vulnerable to overflows. Refer to the man page of `scanf()`, or see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16231386/765294) for example.